# Using Telerik Webforms Controls with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, telerik

I have been searching the web for a concrete and simple example of binding a `Telerik RadComboBox` with a `DataSet` by following the ASP.NET MVC pattern, but couldn't find out a working snippet.

This `DataSet` is present in a Class situated in the Model folder of my project.

Can anybody help me on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really something that's advised. I mean, you *can* do it, but a Web Forms control doesn't follow the MVC Paradigm -- that is, the control contains both view and controller logic.

At best, the union [is an unholy one](http://jesschadwick.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-webforms-controls-in-aspnet-mvc.html).

Datasets also are not a creature of MVC; although I guess technically you could do that.

I don't know your situation, so I can't tell you what your 'best bet' is.

Comment: Ok, I'm really at the begining if discovering both ASP.NET MVC pattern and Telerik controls.

Thanks for the advice, I think I'll forget about the MVC structure for my ongoing project

Comment: What's stopping you from dumping the telerik controls and just going with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I wanted to use the possibility of having a very useful and easy to settle combobox to display a list of thousands people.

Basically, this Telerik tool filter the list dynamically as you type any piece of string that matches a part of listed words.

Comment: You could do the same thing in MVC with JQuery and a little Ajax.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I was just looking at Telerik and being blind to other (cheaper :P) solutions because I have this library available ... shame on me :D
I'll look for a sample code using jquery. Thank you !